# Civicrm upgrade fails to update the database

Tags: wordpress, upgrade, failure

I've run into an odd CiviCRM upgrade problem and am looking for leads on what to try.

Civi 5.61.3 is running within Wordpress 6.2.x, PHP 7.4, mysql 5.7.41
I want to move it to the latest editions of Civi, PHP, and mysql.

The upgrade procedure all goes smoothly BUT, when I go to the update database step:
(.../admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/upgrade&reset=1)
It displays the update page, reminds to make a backup, and asks if I want to proceed.
When I click it to proceed, it sends me immediately to the home page of the web site with NO database update performed, nor any error messages displayed in the usual locations.

Since this is a hosted site, I cloned the site to my local sandbox for further testing.  On the sandbox the upgrade takes place as usual with no problems.

Back on the hosted site, I turned Wordpress debug on, but the upgrade throws no errors nor do any appear in the apache2 logs.  I've tried moving PHP and mysql to newer editions beforehand but that too did nothing to resolve the problem.  I even switched from the site's usual theme to a standard one but that too did nothing.

So... I'm running low on ideas for why the upgrade works fine on my sandbox but fails on the public hosted site without providing any feedback on what may be causing the failure.

I don't think it's a permissions issue because the site works fine within the older editions and prior site upgrades never caused a problem.

Have you seen this before?  How did you resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Have seen this on a few small "local" hostings overconserned by "server security" (in their equivalent of understanding it).
The main issue here is always to get **the real** output from the webserver, PHP and (sometimes) mysql **error** logs - for this you may want to have a few rounds with 1st level support engineers and, if unlucky, a few rounds with the 2nd level support engineers.
Once you get the proper logs,  all turns to be really simple ;-)

The below might worth trying as well (try this in various places, index.php or civicrm.settings.php):

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```